# Rails client_side_validation removing labels and not showing errors in div

Tags: ruby-on-rails, client-side-validation

I followed the https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations instructions and the Railscast for it but still the labels vanishes and no errors show up in my standard

```
  <% if @contactmail.errors.any? %>
  <div id="errorExplanation" class="contact-error">
    <ul>
    <% @contactmail.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <% end %>
```

I use Rails 3.1 and Ruby 1.9.3

Comment: can you please show us the update action that you have in your controller?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much standard

```
 @contact = Contact.find(1)


  respond_to do |format|
    if @contact.update_attributes(params[:contact])

      params[:notice] = 'Texten sparad'

      format.html { render action: "edit", :layout => 'admin' }
      format.json { head :ok }
    else

      format.html { render action: "edit", :layout => 'admin' }
      format.json { render json: @contact.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

I  found [this issue](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/issues/985) on the github repository

I used [the fork proposed there](https://github.com/halida/rails_admin) and everything worked fine